# Recreate Access Query With Several Sub-queries In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

We have recently moved our database from Access to SQL Server and I am wanting to recreate an Access query in SQL Server. This query has been design with several sub-queries in it. Here is the access design view for the main query:

[image]

Has anyone got any ideas of how to achieve this is SQL Server?

I can create some of the sub-queries as views, as they do not call for any parameters to be passed through to them.

My problem is about how to create Sub-queries B and C. Would I create these as temporary tables or separate stored procedures which I can the call from within the main stored procedure?

Any help or links is greatly appreciated as I am stuck as to where to start.

Hopefully, a simplified version of how the 6 Access queries interact with each other. Query F is the query that is run from an Access report.

[image]

Comment: T-SQL supports Sub Queries as well, but sub queries don't expect parameters; functions and stored procedures have parameters. Aren't you just after a `JOIN` here? What was your old Access query, and what have you tried (and why didn't it work) in T-SQL?

Comment: I'm sure it is not as simple as a JOIN. This is because the Access query was made up of other queries which produced 2 set of results which then the main uses to compare against each other. I have not tried anything in T-SQL as I wasn't too sure how to go about it. Plus my end product is an ASP website, so I was wanting to call Stored Procedure A which would then call Stored Procedure B and C to generate results which SP A would use to do the comparison. Also SP B and SP C would use views and tables to generate those results. Sorry if this sounds complicated.

Comment: I am now thinking that temp tables is the answer, so I am having a play around in SQL sever, but wondering when the temp tables would be deleted. After the stored procedure has finished?

Comment: That certainly sounds like you are overcomplicated things.

Comment: Based on the current information, I must agree with Lamu. Can you share a (simplyfied) version of the Access query, please?

Comment: I have just added a further diagram to try to explain that there are 6 access queries that have been created to achieve a report that I want to re-create in an ASP website. The thing was that this was created by a predecessor.

Comment: Are you not able to just click the SQL view of your Access Query designer?  All Access queries generate a SQL script that you can manually modify.

Comment: Just share the sql query that generates those queries.

Comment: I had a think about it over the weekend and have used two temp tables to generate the results for Queries D and E in one store procedure and then use those temp tables to compare against each other. Queries A, B and C I have created as views as these do not require parameters.

There was a lot of SQL for all those queries.

Thanks for your efforts in helping me get there.